# ¿Cómo transformar un objeto de una interfaz en otro de otra interfaz?

Tags: typescript, genericos

estoy recibiendo un estado inicial del formulario genérico que tiene como claves strings y como valores objetos Field. Lo que quiero hacer es una función que me genere dos objetos a partir de este que tengan como clave string y como valor también un string

```js
interface Field {
  name: string;
  required: boolean;
  value: string;
  error?: string;
}

const useForm = <T extends Record<string, Field>>(initialState: T) => {
  // ...
}
```

Ejemplo:

```js
const initialState = {
  userName: {
    name: 'userName',
    required: true,
    error: 'Error en el userName',
    value: 'user name'
  },
  email: {
    name: 'email',
    required: true,
    error: 'Error en el email',
    value: 'user@email.com'
  },
  otroCampo: {
    name: 'otroCampo',
    required: false,
    error: 'Error en este campo',
    value: 'valor de este campo'
  }
}
```

`funcion(initialState, 'error')` y obtengo formErrors:

```js
const formErrors = {
  userName: 'Error en el userName',
  email: 'Error en el email',
  otroCampo: 'Error en este campo'
}
```

`funcion(initialState, 'value')` y obtengo formValues:

```js
const formValues = {
  userName: 'user name',
  email: 'user@email.com',
  otroCampo: 'valor de este campo'
}
```

Donde **initialState** es del tipo *Record<string, Field>* y **formErrors** y **formValues** son del tipo *Record<string, string>*

La idea es que sea genérico, esas claves username o email pueden estar o no. Soy nuevo en typescript y llevo días con esto y no lo puedo sacar.

Answer (score 0):

A tu pregunta le hace falta desarrollo de la solución propuesta, sin embargo, por lo que mencionas considero que tienes la idea de lo que quieres lograr.

En realidad para lograr lo que quieres hacer, no necesitas mucho de TS puesto que con JS puedes lograr el cometido, TS solo te ayudará con el tipado pero eso hasta cierto punto ya lo tienes claro, solo te falta aplicarlo.

Primero podrías utilizar un [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) para definir si se tratará de un `error` o un `value.`

```js
type TypeOfRecordInfo = 'error' | 'value';
```

También necesitarás un tipo que comprenda el tipo -valga la redundancia- `Record<string, string>`, y el cual definirá a `formErrors` y `formValues` ya que no existe diferencia entre ambos salvo el nombre de la variable. Definimos un tipo para que sea más legible dentro del código.

```js
type RecordInfo = Record<string, string>;
```

Siguiendo la misma línea de intentar dar una mejor legibilidad, puedes crear un tipo para `Record<string, Field>`.

```js
type FormRecords = Record<string, Field>;
```

Ya que tienes definidos esos tipos puedes utilizarlos para ayudarte en la función que extraerá la información de tus records. Analizando los requerimientos puedes sacar las siguientes aserciones que te ayudarán a definir tu función:

- Sabes que recibirás un objeto, `FormRecords`, que contiene la información de tus records.
- Esa función también recibirá el tipo de información, `TypeOfRecordInfo`, que necesitas extraer de los records.
- Dicha función te retornará la información extraida de los records, `RecordInfo`.

Por lo que la firma de la función podría ser algo así:

```js
const userForm: (o: FormRecords, t: TypeOfRecordInfo) => RecordInfo
```

Ahora que tenemos definida la firma, podemos tener un poco más claro la lógica que tendrá la función. De cada record perteneciente a `FormRecords`, necesitas obtener el valor de la propiedad `TypeOfRecordInfo`, pero como la propiedad `error` dentro de `Field` es opcional, antes necesitas validar que exista un valor para poder mantener la genericidad, si, esta palabra [existe](https://dle.rae.es/genericidad), en caso de que esto llegue a suceder (que no exista algún error). Lo anterior se ve más o menos así:

```js
const userForm = (o: FormRecords, t: TypeOfRecordInfo): RecordInfo => {
    return Object.keys(o).reduce((acc, value) => {
        return (o[value][t])
            ? { ...acc, [value]: o[value][t] }
            : acc;
    }, {});
}
```

Tomando como referencia los valores que has colocado, la conjunción de todas las partes dará como resultado:

```js
const formValues = userForm(initialState, 'value');
// {
//   "userName": "user name",
//   "email": "user@email.com",
//   "otroCampo": "valor de este campo"
// } 
const formErrors = userForm(initialState, 'error');
// {
//   "userName": "Error en el userName",
//   "email": "Error en el email"
// }
```

El tipo de dato para ambos casos será `RecordInfo`. He eliminado a propósito un error, para que observes que la función puede tratar con eso.

Si quieres ver el código en acción, te dejo este [playground](https://tsplay.dev/Wy5LxW).

Por último me gustaría invitarte a realizar el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y ganar tu primera medalla. También me gustaría aconsejarte leer [Cómo Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para tus futuras preguntas y ver lo importante que puede ser un [ejemplo mínimo reproducible](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Saludos y ¡bienvenido a SOEs!